# php closure in member seems to return same result

Tags: php, function, closures, member

Ive got this lines of code here

```
private function getAllEntrys($query) {
  $this->nav->setQuery($query);
  $entrys = [];

  try {
    $this->nav->collectAll(
      function($res) use (&$entrys) {          
        $entrys = array_merge($entrys, $res['value']);
        return true;
      }
    );
  }
  catch(\Exception $e) {
    // ...
  }

  return $entrys;
}
```

Its basically just calling an time consuming query and collect the results using an closured reference. 
The main issue is, that this member function will always return the first result. No matter how many times you call it and independent from its parameters.

If I just make another instance of this class the issue is gone. But I wish to understand what am I doing wrong with my closure.

Any hints?

Comment: Maybe you should delete this line //return true;

Comment: What does `$this->nav->collectAll()` look like and are you catching an exception?

Comment: Its an REST connector that starts to collect various data.